# Fetch requests hang indefinitely in production - they don't even begin to connect. GET works fine, all other methods don't

Tags: post, xmlhttprequest, cloudflare-workers

I'm stumped. I'm making a POST request to an API using fetch. It's a Vue3 app built with Vite. Everything works locally, also in Vite preview, but when I make a fetch request in production using any method other than GET, the request hangs. The request is logged in network, but absolutely nothing happens - no error, nothing. There's not even any connection information - like the connection doesn't happen at all.

The endpoint is a cloudflare worker. It works fine using GET, the API works fine using curl, however browsers simply won't even begin to connect.

There's no error at all, just an indefinite hang.

Answer (score 0):

Weird one this. The cloudflare worker was cloning the request, passing it to another service, then didn't read the response which caused the cloned request to cancel. This seemed to cause execution to hang for the first request. Didn't happen with GET requests.